# How-To: check if array<T>^ == nullptr ? C++ / CLI

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I've done a pretty basic class in C++/CLI using generics. 
How can I check if the generic array^ equals nullptr?

```
generic<class T> where T: IGenericContainable
public ref class FIBEXGenericContainer abstract : AbstractFIBEXNode
{
public:
    property array<T>^ Children;

public:

    property T default[String^]
    {
        T get(String^ aID)
        {
            if(nullptr == Children)
                Console::WriteLine("this won't happen, because I get an NullReferenceException in the above line");

            for each(T tObj in Children)
            {
                if(aID == tObj->ID)
                    return tObj;
            }

            return T();
        }
    }
};
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `this` is null, not `this->Children`.  A non-virtual function can sometimes be called on a null reference, with the results you see (failure occurs inside the function instead of in the caller).

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for that great piece of advice. I'd have never figured that out for myself. Now that I did a quick look around with google I'm much wiser